# Dirichlet energy

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

From PDE Evans, 2nd edition: Chapter 8, Exercise 17:

> Let $u,\hat{u} \in H_0^1(U)$ both be positive minimizers of the Dirichlet energy $$I[w] := \int_U |Dw|^2 \, dx,$$ subject to the constraint that $$\int_U w^2 \, dx = 1.$$ Suppose also that $u,\hat{u} > 0$ within $U$. Follow the hints to give a new proof that $$u \equiv \hat{u} \quad \text{in }U.$$
>   (Hint: Define $w:= \left(\frac{u^2+\hat{u}^2}2\right)^{1/2}$, $s := \frac{u^2}{u^2+\hat{u}^2}$ and $\eta := \frac{u^2+\hat{u}^2}2$; and show that $$|Dw|^2 = \eta\left|s \frac{Du}u+(1-s)\frac{D\hat{u}}{\hat{u}} \right|^2.$$ Deduce $$|Dw|^2 \le \eta \left(s\left|\frac{Du}u \right|^2+(1-s)\left|\frac{D\hat{u}}{\hat{u}} \right|^2 \right)=\frac 12|Du|^2+\frac 12|D\hat{u}|^2$$ and therefore $\frac{Du}u=\frac{D\hat{u}}{\hat{u}}$ almost everywhere.)
>
> (Belloni-Kawohl, Manuscripta Math. 109 (2002), 229--231)

Okay, I actually proved almost all of the hint without any help (woo-hoo!). So I will not need to show any work here.

I do, however, have a question with the very last line of the hint. How can we prove $\frac{Du}u=\frac{D\hat{u}}{\hat{u}}$ a.e. given the relation $|Dw|^2 \le \frac 12|Du|^2+\frac 12|D\hat{u}|^2$? I did try to expand $|Dw|^2$, simplified a bit, then I got this: $$\left|\frac u{u^2+\hat{u}^2} Du + \frac{\hat{u}}{u^2+\hat{u}^2} D\hat{u} \right|^2 \le |Du|^2+|D\hat{u}|^2$$ but this doesn't seem to lead me anywhere.

Comment: The fact that parabolas have a single extremum point may help...

Comment: Can you please expand? Yes, I know parabolas have a single extremum point ... does that mean I set $Du=0$ or $D\hat{u}=0$ as $u,\hat{u}$ are both said to be minimizers?

Comment: Well, think of $u$ and $\hat{u}$ as points in the function space and the Dirichlet energy as a quadratic function... You may need a calculus of variations for this analogy to work though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If you integrate the last ineqality, you got

$$I[w] \le \frac 12 I[u]+ \frac 12 I[\hat u] = I[u]$$

But $u$ is a minimum of $I$, so all the inequalities are equalities.

Comment: I got the integration part, but why can we just set $\frac 12 I[u]+\frac 12I[\hat{u}]=I[u]$? I also don't see how this helps us obtain $\frac{Du}u=\frac{D\hat{u}}u$. In fact, I'm not even sure how *that* statement establishes uniqueness, except that the statement is true if $u \equiv \hat{u}$...

Comment: Isn't that your assumption? (Both $u$ and $\hat u$ are minimizers)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware $u$ and $\hat{u}$ are minimizers, which is why $I[w] \le \ldots$ is actually $I[w] = \ldots$. However, to say $\frac 12 I[u]+\frac 12I[\hat{u}]=I[u]$ requires having $I[u]=I[\hat{u}]$. But how do we know this? I thought we were trying to *show* this, in fact.

Comment: No.... I think you are given this: $I[u] = I[\hat u]$ (by minimizer I think it means absolute minimum)

Comment: Ohh, now that makes sense: The values of $I[u]$ and $I[\hat{u}]$ are the same, just because $u,\hat{u}$ are both minimizers. Now, I'm still left with showing that statement $\frac{Du}u=\frac{D\hat{u}}u$; can I connect our statement $I[w]=I[u]$ to this in some way?

Comment: How do you show the inequality in your last equation?

Comment: Do you mean the inequality $|Dw|^2 \le \frac 12|Du|^2+\frac 12|D\hat{u}|^2$? I used a triangle inequality, then worked with $\eta$ and $s$.

Comment: So for the equality case, that means two vectors pointing at the same direction. (I guess that shows $\frac {Du}{u} = C(x) \frac{D\hat u}{\hat u}$ for $C>0$)

Comment: And $C=1$ if we want to arrive at $\frac{Du}u=\frac{D\hat{u}}{\hat{u}}$, I take it? This must be when the constraint $$\int_U w^2 \, dx = 1$$ comes into play here.

Comment: Or try to use this (that is hinted in the comment already) $\left|s \frac{Du}u+(1-s)\frac{D\hat{u}}{\hat{u}} \right|^2 = \left(s\left|\frac{Du}u \right|^2+(1-s)\left|\frac{D\hat{u}}{\hat{u}} \right|^2 \right)$ (The LHS is a function convex in $s$)

Comment: I mean the LHS is a strictly convex function. So if equality holds, it must be (1) $s=0$ or $1$ (which is not true in our case) or (2) the two vectors are the same.

Comment: Oh I see now: $s\not=0,1$ because of the restrictions $u, \hat{u} > 0$. So we must be left with the vectors $\frac{Du}u$ and $\frac{D\hat{u}}{\hat{u}}$ being the same.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: What was thoroughly confusing from the problem was that they also had the reader write $\frac 12 |Du|^2+\frac 12|D\hat{u}|^2$. Apparently, it's just a simplication and we don't need that? And we also don't need the constraint $\int_U w^2 \, dx =1$ as well?

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot! Our equality is only "almost everywhere". That's because the integrals $I[u]$ and $I[\hat{u}]$ are equal to each other, I think.

Comment: You have $\frac{Du}{u} = \frac{D\hat u}{\hat u}$, so $D(\log u) = D(\log \hat u)$, so $\log u = \log \hat u +C$ and so $u = C\hat u$. That integral is needed to force $C=1$.

Comment: Ohh, so just square both sides to get $u^2=C^2\hat{u}^2$, integrate over $U$ both sides, then finally use the constraint for both the resulting integrals (since, I know, for the umpteenth time, both $u,\hat{u}$ are minimizers). So we have $$\int_U u^2 \, dx = C^2 \int_U \hat{u}^2 \, dx$$ gives way to $1=C^2 \cdot 1$, namely $C=1$.

Comment: I think I got this now (though, I still believe the "almost everywhere" for $\frac{Du}u=\frac{D\hat{u}}{\hat{u}}$ results from $I[u]=I[\hat{u}]$, unless you have something to convince me otherwise).